# Connecting points with coordinates from columns in a csv file

Tags: pgfplots, csv, segment

I have a csv file containing four columns x1, y1, x2 and y2. I need to draw line segments connecting the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) for each row of the table using `\addplot`. In the following code, file1.csv contains data as follows:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2
3,4,1,5
4,2,1,0
3,3,6,5
...
...
```

I have the following code and `\addplot` part need to be completed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm,graphicx,tikz,float}
\usepackage{enumerate,array}
\usepackage{pgfplots,color}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Segments},
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={Y},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
]

\addplot[] table {file1.csv};
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Happy New Year!

See if the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) works for you:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{file1.cvs}
x1 y1 x2 y2
3  4  1  5
4  2  1  0
3  3  6  5
    \end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    xlabel = {X},
    ylabel = {Y},
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    enlargelimits = 0.1,
            ]
\addplot    table   [x=x1, y=y1]   {file1.cvs};
\addplot    table   [x=x2, y=y2]   {file1.cvs};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, to MWE is added `file1.cvs` from which I remove all commas.

[image]

**Edit:**
Sorry, in my first attempt to help you apparently I misunderstood your problem. As I noted from in my comment, use your table on the way, as you like, is beyond my knowledge, however, if it is possible to reorganize your table as is done in the next MWE, than you will get the following result:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{file1.cvs}
3  4  
1  5
 
4  2  
1  0 

3  3  
6  5
    \end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    xlabel = {X},
    ylabel = {Y},
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    enlargelimits = 0.1,
            ]
\addplot    table   {file1.cvs};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Happy new year! And thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately, it does not connect the points as I expect. Instead, it connects points in the first two columns first and then the points in the next two columns. For example, it connects (3,4) to (4,2) but I need to connect (3,4) to (1,5). On the other hand, I have hundreds of rows in the files, so I need an automated method rather than adding separate \addplot lines.

Comment: @Don, now I see what is your problem. The simplest way is reorganize table to be two column data only. If this is not an option, than I can't help you. It is behind my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! Yes, I think I have to prepare the table as you’ve suggested. In fact, my main question is to know whether there is a way to manipulate the individual entries in a column of a table, just like vector manipulations in a programming language. Thank you very much again @Zarco!